# ¿Cual es la correcta forma de pasar una fecha como parametro?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Siempre tengo problemas con las fechas a la hora de querer pasarlas como parametro a una sentencia en SQL, trato de usar una variable previa, un `Convert` o un `Cast` pero nunca logro encontrar la forma correcta.

Tengo la siguiente sentencia en C# donde estoy construyendo una sentencia Update y estoy enviando 3 parametros, de los cuales dos son valores numéricos y el último es la fecha en cuestión.

```
UpdateStatement = "UPDATE Productos SET PrecioUnitario = " + nPrecioUnitario.ToString() + ", FactorVenta = " + nFactorVenta.ToString() + ", PrecioUnitarioFecha = CONVERT(DateTime,'" + dFecha.ToString() + "',103) WHERE ProductoId = " + nProductoId;
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
```

No es un tema de formato porque estamos 18 de Mayo y la fecha esta llegando 18/05/2016 12:00:00. Primero trate de dejarlo sin convertir, luego lo puse entre comillas y le agregué el Convert y no se al final si existe alguna forma correcta de lograr que una fecha pase de manera directa y sin estos problemas.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Debes usar Parameters, algo semejante a este:

Comment: ¿Qué utilizas para conectarte a la base de datos: ADO, Entity framework, otro framework?

Comment: Estoy usando solo ADO, por ahora.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes siempre usar Parameters, como:

```
new SqlParameter()
{
    ParameterName = "@Unit",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
    Value = _unit
},
```

Con mas contexto/mejor ejemplo:

```
var dtFillRateResults = SQLDBHelper.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(
    ProActWebReportsConstsAndUtils.FILLRATE_STOREDPROC,
    CommandType.StoredProcedure,
    new SqlParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "@Unit",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
        Value = _unit
    },
    new SqlParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "@Member",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
        Value = _memberId
    },
    new SqlParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "@BegDate",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime,
        Value = Convert.ToDateTime(_begindate)
    },
    new SqlParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "@EndDate",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime,
        Value = Convert.ToDateTime(_enddate)
    }
    );
```

...y:

```
public static DataTable ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ProActWebReportsConstsAndUtils.CPSConnStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = EXTENDED_TIMEOUT;
        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
        }

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        . . .
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Según entiendo `dFecha` ya es de tipo `DateTime` no es necesario usar `Convert.ToDateTime` además ese código si bien sirve como referencia no es exactamente el código que el usuario necesita, mas parece copy paste de algún otro lado.

Comment: Es mi propio codigo; trabajo bueno.

Comment: Me refería a que `_unit`, `_memberId`, `_begindate` y `_enddate` no son identificadores que se encuentren en el código de @JuanManuelPalacios mas bien son parte de un código de ejemplo. Creo que para la proxima vez sería mejor adaptar el ejemplo al código que utiliza el OP

Comment: No tienes razon - el poster debes ajustar el codigo a suyo. Esta una idee, no una solucion en si mismo.

Answer (score 3):

No deberias unir lo valores en el string, sino asignar los parametros al objeto command

La estructura deberia ser algo como

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<connection string>"))  
{  
    conn.Open();  

    string query = @"UPDATE Productos SET PrecioUnitario = @preciounitario, 
                        FactorVenta = @fechaventa, PrecioUnitarioFecha = @preciounitariofecha 
                    WHERE ProductoId = @productoid";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preciounitario", nPrecioUnitario);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaventa", nFactorVenta);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preciounitariofecha", dFecha);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productoid", nProductoId);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
```

en este caso se entiende tanto `dFecha` y `nFactorVenta` son del tipo `DateTime`